# Matrices and equivalence of norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Define the norm $\| T\|_2 := \sup\{\| Tx\|_2 : x \in \mathbb R^n \quad \text{s.t.}\quad \| x\|_2 = 1  \}$.

Suppose that $\| T\|_2 \leq C$, if we wanted to define a generic norm $\| T\| := \sup\{\| Tx\| : \| x\| = 1 \}$. Can we use equivalence of norms to conclude that $\| T\| \leq C$?

So far I have that for some $M >0$:

$$
\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\| Tx\| \leq \sup_{\| x\|_2 = 1}M\| Tx\|_2 \leq MC
$$

Comment: You are using the same symbol for a lot of different norms here.  To be clear, when you write $\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\| Tx\|$, do you really mean $\sup_{\|x\|_a = 1}\| Tx\|_b$ where $\|\cdot\|_a$ is some arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ is some other arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @EricWofsey: The second norm that I wrote (without any subscript) is any arbitrary norm on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Then what does $\|Tx\|$ mean?  $Tx$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Sorry, forgot to add this part: $x \in \mathbb R^n$. I just edited it.